# How to fetch results in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have the following 2 tables.

```
| ID | Name        | Category |
|----|-------------|----------|
|  1 | Foo bar     | 3        |
|  2 | Bar foo     | 2        |
|  3 | Baz Foo     | 3        |
|  4 | Baz Foo2    | 1        |
|  5 | Baz Foo3    | 1        |
|  3 | Baz Foo     | 1        |

| ID | Category_name |
|----|---------------|
|  1 | Cat 111       | 
|  2 | Cat 222       | 
|  3 | Cat 3333      |
```

I want to display all categories with counter, example:

```
Cat111 - 3
Cat222 - 2
Cat333 - 2
```

I tried to do it by the following way, but its not working:

```php
$query = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM gallery');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $query_cat = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `pics_cat` WHERE id = '".$row['category']."' GROUP BY category_name"); 
    $rowCat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_cat);
    echo $rowCat['category_name'];
    echo $rowCat['cnt'];
}
```

Comment: set an empty array outside of the while loop and push the results into the array inside the while loop. Afterward you can display the results with a foreach loop.

Comment: FYI `mysqli_query()` requires the `mysqli` connection object as the first argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not sharing the names of the tables, but I assume the first one is `Gallery` and the second one is `pics_cat`

If your tables are not going to be very large, I suggest you to solve everything with a single join query, which simplifies the logic of your script.

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT p.Category_name,COUNT(g.ID) AS cnt FROM `gallery` AS g LEFT JOIN `pics_cat` AS p ON p.ID = g.Category GROUP BY p.ID');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $rowCat['Category_name'];
    echo $rowCat['cnt'];
}
```

If you prefer to do this with 2 queries in a loop, it's much easier to start from the Category table and then move to the gallery

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM `pics_cat` ORDER BY ID');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $query_count = mysqli_query('SELECT COUNT(ID) AS cnt FROM `gallery` WHERE Category = '.$row['ID'].'');
    $row_count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_count);
    echo $row['Category_name'];
    echo $row_count['cnt'];
}
```

Comment: The second example would be much better with a prepared statement created once outside the loop then executed with parameters in the loop

Comment: @Phil Why? There's no user interaction.

Comment: You might want to use a `LEFT JOIN` in case there are categories which have no entries in `gallery`, that way you can return a count of 0.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner prepared statements aren't _only_ good for security. The same statement prepared once and executed multiple times is much more efficient than executing a bespoke query each time. Also, blindly trusting the data in your database is almost as bad as blindly trusting user input. See _"Second-order SQL injection"_

Comment: @Nick totally right. Updating the answer to reflect that

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner isn't it faster (in database) beeing once prepared and executed several times with just different values?

Comment: @AndreaOlivato mysqli_query() still needs a mysqli $link as first param (as Phil has stated).